# How to call a Gradle task in all subprojects?

Tags: java, gradle

Say, I have a hierarchy of Gradle projects and some of them have `java` plugin applied:

```
root
  projA
    projA1
    projA2 (java)
  projB
    projB1 (java)
    projB2 
      projB21 (java)
      projB22 (java) 
  projC (java)
```

I want to execute the `test` task in all subprojects where this task exists: `:projA:projA2:test`, `:projB:projB1:test` and `:projC:test`. Probably I will add more projects in future and I don't want to manually support a list of all test tasks in all subprojects. How can I achieve it?

One thing that came to my mind is something like the following:

```
// In root I iterate over all subprojects and find the task by name causing
// its creation and configuration

tasks.register("testAll") {
  dependsOn subprojects.findResults { it.tasks.findByName("test") }
}
```

I don't like this approach as it goes against [task configuration avoidance](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html) style.

Another option is to iterate over subprojects and check if the `java` plugin is applied there:

```
// In root

tasks.register("testAll") {
  dependsOn subprojects.findAll { it.plugins.hasPlugin("java") }.collect { it.tasks.named("test") }
}
```

It works but I have a filling that I miss something simpler...

**EDIT 1**: Sorry for that but I forgot one important detail - I need to run tests in a subtree of projects. Say, everything down the path `:projB`.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, you want to run tests for all of your submodules.

You can just...do that.

`./gradlew clean test`

This will run the test task in all of the subprojects that have it sufficiently configured.

If you need to run the tasks in a specific subproject, **from the root project** you can specify the subproject you want to run the task.

`./gradlew clean :projB:test`

If your subprojects have a task that needs to run *after* test, then you can do this in your `subprojects` block.

```
subprojects {
    myTask.dependsOn("test")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I missed one important detail in my question. Updated it. Running all tests from the root is indeed not a problem.